# Get value of static field from Class

Tags: java, reflection, static

```
abstract class A {
    static int i = 5;
}

class B extends A {
    static int i = 6;
}

class C extends A {
    static int i = 7;
}
```

Now I have an `ArrayList<Class<? extends A>>`. How can I get the value of the static field from an `Class<? extends A>`?

Comment: Have you looked at the class Javadoc for `Class`? Use `getDeclaredField`.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a painful thing? Are you into self torture? Do you not know that statics are evil -- they make testing *really* difficult, and code that takes SO to explain is excruciatingly difficult to maintain.

Comment: try to make non-static getter which returns you a static variable

Comment: @EngineerDollery Well this is for a game, A is the superclass Enemy and B and C are specific types of enemies. I don't see any other way to make a static method in Enemy that takes a difficulty level and returns a new instance of the respective enemy type.

Comment: You could, instead, use a factory method and the singleton pattern. The real problem with this approach is that you will find it *extremely* difficult to write unit tests around code that collaborates with these classes as it will prove torturous to generate a mock instance of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with reflection

Steps to follow:

- First retrieve the declared field of the class using its variable name
- Check the type of the returned field
- Then call corresponding method on Field to get the field value

Sample code:

```
ArrayList<Class<? extends A>> list = new ArrayList<Class<? extends A>>();
list.add(B.class);
list.add(A.class);


// get the value of first class stored in array
Field f = list.get(0).getDeclaredField("i");
Class<?> t = f.getType();
if (t == int.class) {
    System.out.println(f.getInt(null));
}
```

#### EDIT

As per @Sotirios Delimanolis comments you can get the value directly without checking field type and mathod`Field#getX()` as shown below but it will return `Object` instead of primitive `int`.

```
Field f = list.get(0).getDeclaredField("i");
System.out.println(f.get(null));
```

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Thanks for `getDeclaredField()` I tried with `getField()` first but that access only public member of the class.

Comment: What does `Class<?> t = f.getType();
if (t == int.class)` do? Is it required?

Comment: To check for the the type of the field and based on type `f.getInt()` or `f.getDouble()` methods are called.

Comment: Don't I know that `i` is an int? So can I just get rid of that?

Comment: You can just use `Field#get(..)`, you don't have to go through `getX` where `X` is a primitive type.